EXIFtool reports lower megapixel rating than Camera specifications?
I recently bought a Mavic 3 Pro with the 24mm 20 MP Hasselblad camera and the 3x 70mm 48 MP camera, but the EXIF data says this isn't true. The EXIF data shows the megapixels on the Hasselblad to be 15.7MP and the 3x 70mm to be 9.1MP. This is for RAW DNG on both cameras. Does anyone have an idea why this disparity?
